# Sort and create attribute field to the shapefile

Tags: python, layers, fields-attributes, ogr, query

I am creating a shapefile layer and adding an 'Area' attribute field using the following script:

```
 # Create shapefile layer
drv = ogr.GetDriverByName("ESRI Shapefile")
dst_ds = drv.CreateDataSource(shp_output_path)
srs = osr.SpatialReference(wkt=prj)

dst_layer = dst_ds.CreateLayer(dst_layername, srs=srs)
area_field = ogr.FieldDefn('AREA_ha', ogr.OFTReal)
dst_layer.CreateField(area_field)

for feature in dst_layer:
    geom = feature.GetGeometryRef()
    area = geom.GetArea()
    feature.SetField("AREA", area)
    dst_layer.SetFeature(feature)

dst_ds = None
```

How can I select the 10 largest area features and delete the rest?

Comment: First step is to compute the areas. Use executeSQL, OGR SQL dialect https://gdal.org/user/ogr_sql_dialect.html and OGR_GEOM_AREA.

Comment: @user30184 I am already computing the area using: area = geom.GetArea(). The field has area for all the polygons. I want to sort the values and keep only 10 largest, deleting the rest.

Comment: Sorry, of course you did. But there is place for SQL in the next step `order by area desc offset 10` finds all the features that you do not want to keep.

Answer (score 2):

I would do it something like:

```
def get_area(feature):
    return feature.GetGeometryRef().GetArea()

features = []

for feature in dst_layer:
    features.append(feature)

output = sorted(features, key=get_area, reverse=True)[:10]
```

Comment: sorted() gives an TypeError: 'float' object is not callable

Comment: try now I've fixed the typos

Comment: that worked, so how can I only keep these values from output list in the field and delete rest? sorry i am a newbie and super confused!

Comment: just write them out to a new file like usual https://pcjericks.github.io/py-gdalogr-cookbook/vector_layers.html#create-a-new-shapefile-and-add-data